# EMS server starts

Tags: tibco-ems

Please can you help me for this problem.
I installed `TIBCO EMS` correctly but when I want to start, it shows  this error below.
I used `./tibemsd.sh (like ./tibemsd64 -config ................)`

TIBCO Enterprise Message Service.
Copyright 2003-2017 by TIBCO Software Inc.
All rights reserved.

Version 8.4.0 V14 7/20/2017

> Parameter error: configuration file
>   '/home/tibco/TIBCO_HOME/tibco/cfgmgmt/ems/data/tibemsd.conf' not found
>   or not accessible

I tried to modify the authorization of this file configuration but without results.

Answer (score 0):

I am also get the same problem to start EMS.
In my case, I installed in linux OS.

To start the EMS in GUI mode
go to the path: tib_dir/ems/8.4/bin

[tib_dir is your tibco directory where the ems installed]

Enter the following command
*nohup ./tibemsd –config /home/tibco/TIBCO_HOME/tibco/cfgmgmt/ems/data/tibemsd.conf &*

hope, it's work.